# How do I retrieve a matrix column and row name by a matrix index value?

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, rows

So let's say I have a matrix, mdat and I only know the index number. How do I retrieve the column and row names? For example:

```
> mdat <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, 
    dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3"))) 
> mdat[4] 
[1] 12 
> names(mdat[4]) 
NULL 
> colnames(mdat[4]) 
NULL 
> rownames(mdat[4])
NULL 
> dimnames(mdat[4]) 
NULL
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First you need to get the row and column of that index using `arrayInd`.

```
k <- arrayInd(4, dim(mdat))
```

You can then get the right name by getting that element of the row and column names

```
rownames(mdat)[k[,1]]
colnames(mdat)[k[,2]]
```

Or both at once using `mapply`:

```
mapply(`[[`, dimnames(mdat), k)
```

Comment: In reading this answer again, I wonder if the OP only had the overall index because they ran `which` without `arr.ind=TRUE`.  Future readers: if you're getting that index from `which`, use `arr.ind=TRUE` to get the row and column indices, instead of using `arrayInd`.

Answer (score 8):

Subsetting the matrix first results in a one-element vector that has no names, as you show in your question.  Remember that subsetting creates a completely new object via copying.  There's no way to reference the original `mdat` after subsetting.

This is more clear if you assign the result of subsetting to another object.

```
> m <- mdat[4]
> m
[1] 12
> names(m)  # no names were printed above... so
NULL
```

You really want to access the column/row names first and subset *them*.

```
> colnames(mdat)[3]
[1] "C.3"
> rownames(mdat)[2]
[1] "row2"
```

You can re-assign column/row names similarly.

```
> colnames(mdat)[3] <- "C3"
> rownames(mdat)[2] <- "row.2"
> mdat
      C.1 C.2 C3
row1    1   2  3
row.2  11  12 13
```